# garbd with proxysql and mysql replication

Tags: mysql-5.5, proxysql

Can be configured garbd with proxysql + MySQL Replication?, I installed proxysql with 1 master and two slaves using MySQL replication but I was disputed about to connect garb with proxysql how I was done with galera cluster

Answer (score 0):

garbd is used to a fake Galera cluster member.

It doesn't fake a MySQL server.